# I can't access to a memory location with gdb/mi which I used to access with gdb

Tags: gdb, memory-access

I'm trying to execute `print *((int*)0x00401000)` command on Kmines(a minesweeper game) with gdb and gdb/mi. While using gdb the command works and returns the output `$1=0`. But while using same command with gdb/mi it returns the `^error,msg="Cannot access memory at address 0x400000"` error. Gdb can definitely access that location, there's no doubt for it. But why gdb/mi can't while gdb can?

Comment: Are you sure you are using 0x00401000 address (not 0x400000) in MI mode?

Comment: Well, the command is same so it should work. I also tried the 'print *0x00401000' command but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to mention that I use non-stop mode. So because of it, gdb lets the debuggee run while it executes commands and gdb has to stop the process to access proc/pid/mem and read values from it.So gdb won't be able to access the memory if no thread has been stopped.

Edit: Some memory-examination functions such as `disas` works while some others such as `print` and `x` does not. So unfortunately, this answer is partially true.